# jQuery .html() | Will it include inline style?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Say I have something like this setup.

```
<div id="error">
    <p style="color:green">Success.</p>
    <p style="color:red">Failure.</p>
    <p style="color:green">Success.</p>
</div>
```

and in my javascript I run something like this.

```
var response = $('#error').html();
if (response.indexOf('red') === -1) {
    /*do stuff if #error has no style tags that have the color:red*/
}
```

Will that work or do I need to go about doing this a different way? I'd like some insight, thanks.

Comment: It's horrible, but it will potentially work.

Comment: `html()` will fetch the style. But as plalx has mentioned above, this seems to be a very bad idea.

Comment: So how should I go about this if thats not the best way?

Comment: It is not pretty, but I would have done it something like `var isRed = $('#error > p').filter(function(){
    return $(this).css('color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';
}).length > 0;

console.log(isRed)`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Will `element.style.color` always be the same in every browsers or some might convert the value? You can edit my answer if your approach is safer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So how should I go about this if thats not the best way?

The best way (or a better way) would be to give a **failure** class to `p` elements rather than trying to check against styles. But if you have no choice...

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TKvj5/)

There are various ways, the first one is closer to your initial line of thoughts:

```
if ($('#error > p[style*="color:red"]').length) {
    console.log('red');
}
```

A different approach which is slightly better in my opinion:

```
var redPs = $('#error > p').filter(function () {
    return this.style.color === 'red';
});

if (redPs.length) console.log('red again');
```

Comment: +1. You were a minute too quick and added an extra option also. Only modification that I was thinking of is `*` instead of `p` just in case there are other tags like `span` etc.

Comment: Thanks dude<3 Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will take inline CSS. If you have tried opening up a console, you have known that.

However seeing your need. I recommend using Jquery data attribute. Passing jQuery data attribute you can find whether the message is an error or success.